# Visual Studio: generating code upon xsd problems with integers

Tags: c#, xsd, code-generation, integer, xsd.exe

Can anyone tell me, why integer elements in xsd are being converted in String fields?

```
<xs:element name="OwnerID" type="xs:integer"/>
```

into

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "integer")]
public string OwnerID
{
    get
    {
        return this.ownerIDField;
    }
    set
    {
        this.ownerIDField = value;
    }
}
```

my first assumption that all fields are strings attributed by real datatype was not right - dates are interpretered as dates, bools as bools  - what's wrong with integer?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
<xs:element name="OwnerID" >
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int" />
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: We've got the solution almost simultaneously -)

Comment: It's sufficient to just replace xs:integer with xs:int

Answer (score 2):

sq33G's answer is correct, but I want to add that the reason your original XSD element

```
<xs:element name="OwnerID" type="xs:integer"/>
```

is converted to a string is because per [W3C Numeric DataTypes](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_numeric.asp), xs:interger represents any integer value.  Since is not confined to a 32 or 64-bit number and there is no numeric data type in C# that can handle an unbounded integer, the Deserializer is choosing a string type since it is the only type that can safely handle this value.

Comment: I need to correct myself - i remembered the behavior incorrectly.  xs:integer does map to the System.Decimal type